# How to search in two different wordpress blogs by using a single searchform?

Tags: search

How can i get search results from two different blogs [ www.mysite.com and www.blog.mysite.com ] using a single search form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the setup; if they are setup as multisite, check this plugin: [Multisite Global Search](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-global-search/)

If that doesn't work, I'd try custom Google search. They should allow you to search on both sites.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Barry's idea!

I can retrive search results by switching two databases, but i cant show combined results. 
For example i have to show results from first blog and then i have to show the next blog's results.

I find pagination for the search results also difficult. So [Google custom search](http://www.google.com/cse) is the easy and possible solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The other option would be to write a custom page where it searches one db switches db's search again and switch back. (or table prefix)

But without more information about your setup.

I'd go for Google Custom Search